# Appending a value to all columns

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a "simple" question yet I have not found an answer to it nor have I gotten my code to work. I have a bunch of columns, and I want to append the average of the last column to ALL columns.  For example, say I have:

```
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4
1 1 1 1 1
```

The average of column 5 is 2.5. I can calculate the average, but what I want is this:

```
2 2 2 2 2 2.5
3 3 3 3 3 2.5
4 4 4 4 4 2.5
1 1 1 1 1 2.5
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk '$(NF+1) = 2.5' file
```

If you want `awk` to do all the work for you:

```
$ awk '
  FNR == NR { s += $5; i++; next }
  { $(NF+1) = s/i; print }
' file file
2 2 2 2 2 2.5
3 3 3 3 3 2.5
4 4 4 4 4 2.5
1 1 1 1 1 2.5
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Could you please explain what exactly is happening? Particularly with your second response.

Comment: @Dani: The first one just add a new field to every line, and make use of `awk` default `print` action. In the second one, you process the `file` two times, the first time is when `FNR == NR`, you calculate the sum of 5th fields `s += $5`, record how many lines `i++`, the second time when `FNR == NR` is false, you do the same thing as the first approach.